# ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved on android studio 1.2.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio

Im unable to extend the ActionBarActivity i've tried all these possible solutions :
import actionBar
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
changed the app theme to light as well as material light 
tried changing the app theme on the manifest file to Theme.AppCompat.light
i installed the repository and library directory in the sdk manager. ive updated it as well .
even then i get an error

Comment: Use: extends AppCompatActivity.

Comment: what error?! tell us ore information

Comment: Have you sync your project with Support Library?

Comment: Are you syncing gradle files after doing any change?

Answer (score 2):

The class `ActionBarActivity` is depreciated. Use `AppCompatActivity` instead. click [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) for further info.

Comment: edit your question with your specific requirements and what do you receive in Logcat